# Multiple loops for predefined amounts in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, multiprocessing

Basically I don't know what I need to do to accomplish this..

I have two loops that will loop for different durations each:

```
import time

while True:
    print "Hello Matt"
    time.sleep(5)
```

and then another loop:

```
import time

while True:
    print "Hello world"
    time.sleep(1)
```

I need to incorporate both loops in a program and both need to run at the same time and process data independently, and there is no need to share data between them. I guess I'm looking for Threads or Multiprocessing but I'm not sure how to implement it for something like this.

Comment: Look at the examples (the second one): http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of [`Thread`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) is enough for your purpose:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def foo():
    while True:
        print "Hello Matt"
        time.sleep(5)

def bar():
    while True:
        print "Hello world"
        time.sleep(1)

a = Thread(target=foo)
b = Thread(target=bar)
a.start()
b.start()
```

Comment: Very awesome, both extremely valid answers. Going with this one because it seems much cleaner. Question.. is there any harm in consolidating the last four lines into two by added `.start()` to the end of the two threads above them?

Comment: @Matthew Glad it helped. There is no problem with calling `start()` directly, as long as you don't need the reference to the object (e.g., if you are not going to use another method). For your example, it is completely valid.

Comment: I see that you `.start()` the thread. Is there ever a need to `.stop()` a thread? Garbage collection?

Comment: @Matthew No, a thread finishes or is abruptly stopped - there is no `stop()` method. They aren't deleted by garbage collection, even there's always list of all active `Threads` in [`threading.enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate). If you want to finish one of the previous threads, use a boolean variable instead of `True` in the while loop, and change the value of the flag when you want to stop it.

Comment: Very very awesome. I guess the only issue I'm running into now is that if I a variable as True within a thread, another thread isn't seeing that the variable is true now. Do you need an example??

Answer (score 1):

To do that you can use the module threading, like this:

```
import threading
import time

def f(n, str):     # define a function with the arguments n and str
    while True:
        print str
        time.sleep(n)

t1=threading.Thread(target=f, args=(1, "Hello world"))    # create the 1st thread
t1.start()                                                # start it

t2=threading.Thread(target=f, args=(5, "Hello Matt"))     # create the 2nd thread
t2.start()                                                # start it
```

ref.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html